# How to post a form with fetching?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to send a post with fetch an API.

My fetch is working because it returns `200` and sends the request but it sends an empty form.

It cannot take the values in the form input. Where is my mistake and how can I fix it?

```
...  
  const [contract, setContract] = useState("");
  const form = useRef(null);
  const submit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const data = new FormData(form.current);
    fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_ENDPOINT + "user/me/contract", {
      method: "POST",
      body: data,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("fray_access_token")}`,
      },
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((json) => setContract(json.contract));
  };
return( ...
<form ref={form} onSubmit={submit}>
    
    <Input
        required
        type="text"
        value={contract.name}
        onChange={(e) =>
            setContract({ ...contract, name: e.target.value })
                      }
    />
    <Input
        required
        type="text"
        value={contract.surname}
        onChange={(e) =>
            setContract({ ...contract, surname: e.target.value })
                      }
     />
     <Input
          required
          type="email"
          value={contract.emai}
          onChange={(e) =>
          setContract({ ...contract, email: e.target.value })
          }
      />         
</form>
...)
```

Comment: send contract as Post data

Comment: What does 'data' refer to?

Comment: What does the json.contract return?

Comment: Please show the entire component

Comment: Your Content-Type header claims you are sending JSON, but your data is generated from a FormData object which generates multi-part form data and you haven’t shown us the server-side code so we don’t know if it supports JSON, multi-part, both, or neither.

Comment: @georgewashingmachine ````const data = new FormData(form.current);```` I am using for initializing the form.

Comment: @msefer It returns null

Comment: @MuratCemYALIN How can I do that?

Comment: body: contract inside fetch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Update]:

You can either remove the `application/json` header and let browser post the form data implicitly using the `multipart/form-data` content-type :

```
const submit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const data = new FormData(form.current);
    fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_ENDPOINT + "user/me/contract", {
      method: "POST",
      body: data,
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("fray_access_token")}`,
      },
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((json) => setContract(json.contract));
  };
```

As @Quentin pointed out, we cannot serialise `FormData` using `JSON.stringify` so it's better to use explicit function to do it for you:

```
const serialize = (data) => {
    let obj = {};
    for (let [key, value] of data) {
        if (obj[key] !== undefined) {
            if (!Array.isArray(obj[key])) {
                obj[key] = [obj[key]];
            }
            obj[key].push(value);
        } else {
            obj[key] = value;
        }
    }
    return obj;
}

const submit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const data = new FormData(form.current);
    fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_ENDPOINT + "user/me/contract", {
      method: "POST",
      body: typeof data !== 'string' ? JSON.stringify(serialize(data)): data,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("fray_access_token")}`,
      },
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((json) => setContract(json.contract));
  };
```

More details : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: I rewrite my code like this but it still send  null, but at least it returns json now, {"name":null,"surname":null,"email":null}

Comment: @edche issue is with `data` then, and not `fetch`. Can you do `console.log(data)` after `const data = new FormData(form.current);` ?

Comment: `FormData` objects do not serialise to JSON

Comment: @edche I believe you can remove the `content-type` header and let browser post it as `multipart/form-data` implicitly. Does your server require it to be `application/json`?

Comment: It is a great answer thank you, but still get nothing. Could it be because of how to I get data from form?
I mean I am using 
````value={contract.name}
        onChange={(e) =>
            setContract({ ...contract, name: e.target.value })
                      }````
And can it be wrong?

Comment: @edche why don't you just use the state instead of using `ref` to get the formdata? 
How about `const data = {... contract}` and then use the data to make API call now?

Comment: @KanishkAnand I am new to react so I cannot figure out what should I use. But I'll try it

Comment: @KanishkAnand I get an error contract is not iterable

Comment: @edche Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240303/discussion-between-kanishk-anand-and-edche).

Comment: @KanishkAnand I totally change my props and now it is works. Thank you for all your time. You help me very much

Comment: @edche great. Please upvote/accept if it helped you :)

Comment: @KanishkAnand I did all! thanks again